# Flutter run with failure

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk

I'm doing a mobile intership and learning flutter, I have configured my machine to run and build my aplication apk on my cellphone, yesterday I switch my HDD to SSD and here we go again to download and install everything, now when i try run my app i got this: **FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.** And that is the two failures:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseRenderscript'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android.
     Required by:
         project :
Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android.
Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-android/guava-28.1-android.pom
O conteúdo não é permitido no prólogo.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':javaPreCompileRelease'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android.
     Required by:
         project :
Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android.
Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-android/guava-28.1-android.pom
O conteúdo não é permitido no prólogo.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Also, when i run the flutter doctor i got this issue:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

but when a try to run **flutter doctor --android-licenses** i recive this log error:

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema      
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)      
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)   
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
    ```
````

Comment: did try running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Yes i have try, but I also got another error, the log is at the final of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it just uninstalling and installing again the Android Studio and Flutter, if you got this problem maybe your Android Studio is corrupt.